# Recording calls using twilio rest api

Tags: node.js, twilio, twilio-api

I am using twilio's rest API's to make and record calls.

```
  client.calls.create({
        url:" <my callback url>",
        to: " <called number> ",
        from: <calling number>,
        recordingStatusCallback: <my recording url>,
        Record: "true",
        sendDigits: "1234"
  }, function(err, call) {
        if(err){
           console.log(err);
        }
        else{
           console.log("Call connected");
        }
  });
```

Now, I am unable to understand one thing. Since I have already set the recording property, When twilio makes a call at my callback url, What twiML am I supposed to send if I want to record the entirety of the call ??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Twilio developer evangelist here.

Because you have set the [`record` parameter](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/rest/making-calls#post-parameters-optional) in the request to make the call you don't need to return return any more TwiML to record the whole call.

You just need to return TwiML to do whatever else that you are then recording, like forward to another number with [`<Dial>`](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/twiml/dial) or [`<Play>`](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/twiml/play) the user a message.

Comment: What if I only want to record the call. What twiml should I send then? I tried sending an empty response but it disconnects the call.

Comment: You mean record a message? Then you probably don't want to set `Record` on the request, rather just use the [`<Record>` TwiML](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/twiml/record).

Comment: No, I just want to record complete outgoing call. In my case I don't want the call to dial( <dial> ) someone or play (<play>) some message . I just want to record the entire call. So, what twiml to send here??

Comment: When you make an outgoing call with the REST API, you only have one leg of the call, between the person you're dialling and Twilio. What else do you want to do with this call? What should the person who is called hear or do with the call?

Comment: My use case is a bit different. I do not want to do anything with the call except record it because the calls that I initiate are part of some meetings being hosted by a 3rd party. So all I want to do is to be a silent (but recording ) participant in those meetings.

Comment: Ok, so you're dialling straight to the third party conference? In that case you should use `<Record>` instead of setting it in the REST API call.